# MySQL Connector/Net Bulk Uploader not finding file on remote server

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio

I have pored through many pages trying to find an answer but have had no luck.  I have a .NET page built in C# that has been working fine until a few days ago.  Now it isn't working and I'm pulling my hair out to find out why.

The page has a file uploader that uploads a .csv file and saves it to a folder on the web server.  Then it uses the MySQL Bulk Uploader to insert the records into the database on another server.

I have confirmed the file is uploading to the correct folder, but when MySQL tries to insert the records, it fails with the message  "File 'E:\inetpub\wwwroot\training\data_uploads\filename.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)"

This page has worked for several years without any problem, but I updated some of the NuGet packages and removed some that were not being used, and now it's stopped working.  What am I missing?  Is there a package or a .dll I need to add back in?  Unfortunately, I don't remember what I removed.

Here's the code I'm using:

```cs
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            
            //if file is selected for upload
            if (btnSelectFile.HasFile)
            {
                //upload data file to server
                string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/data_uploads/" + btnSelectFile.FileName));
                btnSelectFile.SaveAs(path);

                string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameOfConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
                conn.Open();

                //get rid of old data
                MySqlCommand truncateTerms = new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE terms_temp;", conn);
                truncateTerms.ExecuteNonQuery();


                //create bulk uploader and set parameters
                var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
                bl.TableName = "terms_temp";
                bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
                bl.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
                bl.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
                bl.FileName = path;
                bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 2;

                //insert data
                var inserted = bl.Load(); //This is where it fails


                conn.Close();
    //do some other stuff
     catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label1.Text =  ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: No source control of your code base? Secondarily, any possibility it's a permissions issue? (Not sure why that would've changed but I never rule that out as a possibility.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're bulk-loading a file that's stored on the *web* server, not the database server, you need to set `MySqlBulkLoader.Local = true`, to indicate that the file is local to the database client. Otherwise, the server will give an error that the file isn't found.

For [security reasons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html) you will also need to set `AllowLoadLocalInfile=true` in your connection string to enable this feature.

Comment: Thanks so much Bradley Grainer!.  You nailed it.  Apparently when I updated/removed the NuGet packages it modified the connection string in the web.config file and removed AllowLoadLocalInfile=True.  Once I added it back in everything works as it should.  Most grateful!